# Automatic browse a list of urls and then save them as html web page

Tags: url, browser

I would like to know that is there any online or desktop application or tool that can browse automatically a list of all urls and save each page as html document in a directory. If anyone knows then please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for Java.

It's a headless browser that is decent at handling pages with Javascript and Ajax.  It also supports HTTPS.